# Hyperledger Composer with javascript

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I am a beginner with hyperledger composer. I want to retrieve data from server such as [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp)  that use it in javascript file of hyperledger composer.

 How can I achieve it?

 

below, it is example from [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_ajax_first) that I use in script file of hyperledger composer.

```
/**
 * Sample transaction processor function.
 * @param {org.acme.sample.SampleTransaction} tx The sample transaction instance.
 * @transaction
 */
function sampleTransaction(tx) {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
      }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
    xhttp.send();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use call-outs in Composer transaction functions. But remember with smart contract transactions, all peers executing the transaction logic must return a deterministic result  - else your transaction will fail to be endorsed (you probably knew that, just saying)

See more details and examples here -> https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/integrating/call-out

```
function handlePost(postTransaction) {
  var url = 'https://composer-node-red.mybluemix.net/compute';

  // call-out
  return post( url, postTransaction)
    .then(function (result) {
      // alert(JSON.stringify(result));
        postTransaction.asset.value = 'Count is ' + result.body.sum;

        // now update an Asset Registry (Composer)
        return getAssetRegistry('org.example.sample.SampleAsset')
        .then(function (assetRegistry) {
            return assetRegistry.update(postTransaction.asset);
        });
    });
}
```